# Display messages std::cout from remote machines

Tags: ros, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I wonder that there are some commands to open a new terminal from master machine ( pc) and to display some messages of std:: out in remote machines using roslaunch ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258424/display-messages-std::cout-from-remote-machines/) by [phivu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29902/phivu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS provides the `/rosout` topic, logging functions in both [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging) (`ROS_INFO()`) and [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging) (`rospy.loginfo()`), and [rqt_console](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_console), to facilitate viewing log messages from remote machines. (and much, much more!)

There's a [rospy Tutorial on Logging](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Logging) and describes how all of these tools fit together.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phivu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29902/phivu/) on 2017-04-02**:
Hi  ahendrix, thank you for ur reply. Currently, I used ROS_INFO in remote machines and RQT_console to read messages in master machines using ROS launch file. The problem is that the amout of message for two nodes must be displayed constantly and I do not know how to separate them.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-02**:
The filters in the bottom portion of rqt_console allow you to selectively hide, highlight, or show messages from only some nodes (or based on other criteria).